# How to use selectize input with dplyr in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I would like to make this simple app work correctly. It is supposed allow the user to select any number of variables in the `dplyr::starwars` dataset and display the distinct combinations of those variables.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Use selectize with dplyr"),
   selectizeInput("distinct_vars", "Select distinct", choices = names(starwars), multiple = T),
   dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
   output$table <- renderDataTable({
        req(input$distinct_vars)
        arg_list <- rlang::parse_quosures(paste(input$distinct_vars, collapse = ";"))

        starwars %>% 
             distinct(!!arg_list)
   })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I'm having difficulty with the line `distinct(!!arg_list)`. I would like to pass arguments to the `distinct` function as a list. If I replace this line with `distinct(!!arg_list[[1]])` then the app works correctly but only for the first variable selected. I would like to allow the user to select any number of variables and the pass the user's selection(s) on to dplyr functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For multiple vars, we need `!!!` instead of `!!`

```
 ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Use selectize with dplyr"),
   selectizeInput("distinct_vars", "Select distinct", choices = names(starwars), multiple = T),
   dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
   output$table <- renderDataTable({
        req(input$distinct_vars)
        arg_list <- rlang::parse_quosures(paste(input$distinct_vars, collapse = ";"))

        starwars %>% 
             distinct(!!! arg_list)
   })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-output

[image]